# Is $T$ a compact mapping from $W_{0}^{1,2}\left(\Omega\right)$ into itself?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, compact-operators

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset in $\mathbb{R}^{6}$ and $f$ be in $L^{8}\left(\Omega\right)$. For any $w$ in $W_{0}^{1,2}\left(\Omega\right)$, define $T\left(w\right)$ be in $W_{0}^{1,2}\left(\Omega\right)$ such that

$${\displaystyle \int_{\Omega}\nabla\left(Tw\right)\nabla\phi dx}={\displaystyle \int_{\Omega}f\phi w dx}
 \ \ \ \  \forall\phi\in W_{0}^{1,2}\left(\Omega\right)$$

Is $Tw$ well defined? Is $T$ a compact mapping from $W_{0}^{1,2}\left(\Omega\right)$ into itself?

Comment: If Yingyong's answer is correct then I am a little bit confused about the relevance of the $6$ and $8$, since it seems like it should work for any dimension and any $L^p$ exponent which is at least $2$. I'm also a little confused that the right side doesn't have a $w$ in it (the question is much more interesting in that case).

Comment: The way this is written, $Tw$ does not depend on $w$ at all. Please clarify.

Comment: I would guess that it's $Tf$ instead.

Comment: No way, it's not $Tf$ @JohnMa

Comment: @user110834 : Though you have accepted an answer, you should clarify the question a little bit. As 1999 said, your $T\omega$ has nothing to do with $\omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Lax-Milgram there exists only one $\theta\in W_0^{1,2}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega\nabla\theta\cdot\nabla\phi dx=\int_\Omega f\phi dx
\end{equation}
for all $\phi\in W_0^{1,2}$. So in fact $T$ is well defined, linear and continuous from $W_0^{1,2}$ to $W_0^{1,2}$ with norm $|\theta|_{W_0^{1,2}}$. Obviously it is compact, since the range of $T$ has only one element $\theta$.

---

(Sorry that I made a mistake before. I hope this time every thing should be right.)

As Ian said, we can consider the problem
\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega\nabla\theta\cdot\nabla\phi dx=\int_\Omega f\omega\phi dx
\end{equation}

for all $\phi\in W_0^{1,2}$. First we should prove that the RHS is in fact in $H^{-1}$. We obtain
\begin{align}
|\int_\Omega f\omega\phi dx|&\leq\int_\Omega |f\omega\phi|dx\\
&\leq c\int_\Omega |f|^3+|\omega|^3+|\phi|^3dx\\
&=:S_1+S_2+S_3.
\end{align}
Since $f\in L_8$, $S_1$ is finite, and using the Rellich's embedding theorem we know $W_0^{1,2}$ is embedded in $L_3$ (consider the Sobolev numbers 1-6/2=0-6/3), So the functional at RHS is linear and continuous in $W_0^{1,2}$ and therefore $T$ is well defined.

The second part in still in consideration. (What I wrote before was wrong, sorry about that. $H^2$ is not compactly embedded into $H_0^1$.)

---

Ok, I found a proof that $T$ is compact if we assume the bdry is lipschitzian: Indeed, we can show that $fw$ is in $L_2$ and see that the dimensions really play a role here. We have
\begin{align}
\int (fw)^2&\leq c\int f^6+w^3+w^3<\infty,
\end{align}
the inequality follows from the same argument as before. By regularity theory we know that the solution $\theta=\bar{T}w$ in fact lies in $H^2$, and the identity operator $I:H^2\rightarrow H^1$ is by Rellich's theorem compact, so the decomposition $T=I\circ \bar{T}:H_0^1\rightarrow H^1$ is compact. We also know that all solutions are really in $H_0^1$, so $T$ is compact between $H_0^1$ and $H_0^1$.

Comment: What is $\omega$ in your inequalities?

Comment: Well, $\omega$ should be $w$ in this case, sorry about that, I can't distinguish both letters sometimes.

Comment: So it seems that you are the one who understand the OP's question. Can you edit the question so that it is clear how $T\omega$ is defined? @Yongyong

Comment: @JohnMa But i'm not sure if this was the original question... and I can't edit since it is less than 6 characters.

Comment: How would you edit it if you can? @Yongyong

Comment: Just replace $f$ by $fw$, and for this case i've done in the answer.

Comment: @Yongyong : Cool. Since the OP has accepted your answer, I would assume that this is the correct interpretation.